# how to fix yarn.lock and package-lock json mix

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

So i was going on with my nodejs project and was trying to install a package with npm, but it got stuck in the process. I found I could use yarn which i, the very next second, did. It worked, but now im trying to host it on Heroku and I have both, `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`. If i delete any, the dependencies get outdated. how can i fix this?

My dependencies:
`express`,
`passport`,`mongoose`,`ejs`

I tried and searched the web for a while but nothing seemed to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `yarn install` and it will install all the dependencies again with updateing the `yarn.lock`. And then you can delete `package-lock.json`.